# How to show a dialog after the user select a row of a <p:datatable>?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have this datatable:

```
<h:form id="form">
<p:dataTable id="tblInfo" var="ref" value="#{consultasBean.listaRefacciones}" paginator="true" rows="10" selectionMode="single" selection="#{consultasBean.refaccionSeleccionada}" rowKey="#{ref.idRefaccion}">
       <p:column headerText="Equipo">
          <h:outputText value="#{ref.equipo}" />
       </p:column>
       <p:column headerText="Marca">
          <h:outputText value="#{ref.marca}" />
       </p:column>
       //More colums here...
</p:dataTable>
```

And I want to show this dialog after the user select a row:

```
<p:dialog id="myDialog" widgetVar="refaccionDialog" header="Detalle Refaccion" resizable="false" width="300" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">
     <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
          <h:outputText value="Info:" />
          <h:outputText value="#{consultasBean.refaccionSeleccionada.equipo}" />
     </h:panelGrid>
     //More things here...
 </p:dialog>
```

And this is part of my bean (viewscoped):

```
private List<RefaccionBean> listaRefacciones = null;
private RefaccionBean refaccionSeleccionada = null;
// setters and getters...
```

`listaRefacciones` already has info, so dont worry about how it gets it.

I know i have to use p:ajax but just dont know how.

I was checking [this](http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf) (example 1 is what i want) but the info is too old and does not work now.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include a p:ajax inside your table

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="PF('refaccionDialog').show()" update=":dialogId" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is not working, I included that line in the table and put id="myDialog" in the `<p:dialog>` tag. So the update of the `<p:ajax>` is update="myDialog" now. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: this is how i did it: `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="PF('refaccionDialog').show()" update=":form:myDialog" />` and the problem is that the dialog does not show me the info and if i have more than 10 row (will result in more pages of the datatable) and i select one row; after that I cant move to other pages (of the datatable and the navigation). **I updated some code of the question**

Comment: do you have any javascript error ? check your console.

Comment: i think so, the console is full after i select a row. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: I can't guess what errors do you have! you should post the full log

Comment: I think this is the error: `DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled or you need to define rowKey attribute` and if I remove the rowKey attribute the info is never showed in the datatable.

Comment: `rowKey="ref.idRefaccion"` is missing the opening and closing.. it should be like this  `rowKey="#{ref.idRefaccion}"`

Comment: Thank You very much! It was so simple... thanks for your patience

Answer (score 1):

**rowKey** attribute of datatable is wrongly written.
it should be like as follows

```
  rowKey="#{ref.idRefaccion}"
```

The datatable code should as follows

```
   <h:form id="form">
   <p:dataTable id="tblInfo" var="ref" value="#{consultasBean.listaRefacciones}" paginator="true" rows="10" selectionMode="single"
      selection="#{consultasBean.refaccionSeleccionada}" rowKey="#{ref.idRefaccion}">
   <p:column headerText="Equipo">
      <h:outputText value="#{ref.equipo}" />
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="Marca">
      <h:outputText value="#{ref.marca}" />
   </p:column>
   //More colums here...
   </p:dataTable>
```